# Entity Framework `LoadWith` not bringing back data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Here is my model

```
 public IEnumerable<PostJob> GetAllJobsByUserId(int id)
 {
     using (var context = new CleanerDataContext(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog='Cleaning Lady';Integrated Security=True"))
     {
         var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
         loadOptions.LoadWith<PostJob>(c => c.Cleaner);
         loadOptions.LoadWith<PostJob>(c => c.User);
         context.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
         return context.PostJobs.Where(r => r.userId == id).ToList();
     }
 }
```

In my view I am trying to access properties in 'Cleaner'

```
@foreach (var k in Model.AllJobs)
{
    <div class="panel panel-default instructions">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span>Date: @k.date.ToShortDateString() From: @k.timeFrom Until: @k.timeUntil</span>
            <span>Price: @k.Cleaner.Price</span>
            <span>Total: </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

But I am getting an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why am I getting this error if am loading 'Cleaner' together with 'PostJob'?

Here is the postjob in the database

[image]I am using linq

Comment: Do you have navigation properties defined for Cleaner and User?  Why are you including User? your view you've posted doesn't use any properties from User.  Include will include the entire other entity in a linq query.  you are only using 1 property.  it would be better to define a view model and populate it from your context and return the view model to the view.

Comment: I was going to use User also. I can't populate it b4 because it is a list. How would I match each cleaner with each cleanerid?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Include()` in return

```
 return context.PostJobs.Include(x=>x.Cleaner).Where(r => r.userId == id).ToList();
```

your method will be

```
public IEnumerable<PostJob> GetAllJobsByUserId(int id)
 {
     using (var context = new CleanerDataContext(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog='Cleaning Lady';Integrated Security=True"))
     {
         var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
         loadOptions.LoadWith<PostJob>(c => c.Cleaner);
         loadOptions.LoadWith<PostJob>(c => c.User);
         context.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
         return context.PostJobs.Include(x=>x.Cleaner).Where(r => r.userId == id).ToList();
     }
 }
```

Don't forget to include

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Cleaners.Models.PostJob>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: `using System.Data.Entity;` use this namespace

Comment: now getting  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `Cleaner` has a reference of `Cleaner` ?

Comment: Postjob database has cleanerId in it which has a reference to cleaner

Comment: @N.Sch are you using separate accounts? how is it that you can add details about OP?

Comment: I was talking about `PostJob.cs` and `Cleaner.cs` not database table

Comment: I am not sure what PostJob.cs is?